# Extjs combobox pagination not showing

Tags: extjs, combobox, pagination

i want to create a combobox with pagination

this is the combobox

```
Ext.define('BOP.view.dateConsum.DateConsumView',{
extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
config:{
    xtype:'tabpanel',
    title: 'Date consum',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-home',
    closable: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Alege furnizorul',
            store: Ext.create('BOP.store.Furnizor'),
            pageSize: true,
            minChars: 1,
            triggerAction: 'query',
            anchor: '100%',
            displayField: 'furn_nume',
            valueField: 'furn_id',
            layout: 'fit',
            width:260,
            height: 50
        }
    ]
    }
});
```

this is the store

```
Ext.define('BOP.store.Furnizor', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    model: 'BOP.model.Furnizor',

    pageSize:15

});
```

and this is the model

```
Ext.define('BOP.model.Furnizor', {
    extend: 'BOP.model.Base',

fields: [{
    name: 'furn_id',
    type: 'int'
}, {
    name: 'furn_nume',
    type: 'string'
},{
    name: 'furn_cod_sap',
    type: 'string'
}],

proxy: {
    url: '/furnizori',
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
```

the thing is, the request is made just like it should sending as params page, start, limit and query but for some reason the pagination is not showed
i am using the modern theme, version 6.5.3

Comment: Please show your backend code.

Answer (score 0):

According to Extjs document:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#cfg-pageSize

> If greater than 0, a Ext.toolbar.Paging is displayed in the footer of the dropdown list and the filter queries will execute with page start and limit parameters. Only applies when queryMode = 'remote'.
>   Defaults to:0

so your combo code should like this:

```
{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Alege furnizorul',
        store: Ext.create('BOP.store.Furnizor'),
        pageSize: 100, //for example 100 per page
        queryMode: 'remote',  // and set remote for queryMode
        minChars: 1,
        triggerAction: 'query',
        anchor: '100%',
        displayField: 'furn_nume',
        valueField: 'furn_id',
        layout: 'fit',
        width:260,
        height: 50
    }
```

Comment: @lessan we do not have pageSize in Extjs **modern**. Test this code in classic.

Comment: Why it will show valueField: 'furn_id' in the dropdown instead of showing displayField: 'furn_nume'

Answer (score -1):

Just add `pageSize: true` to the comboBox and it will show.